# automatically sorting data structure for objects based on key?

Tags: c#

I would like a structure to automatically sort data for me based on an associated key, but once this is done I never have to grab any of the objects with the key, I just want to take the first one off the list. In my specific case each object has an associated float value, and I want to order them from low to high.

For example I want to be able to sort a list of integers, but by their corresponding float 'keys' and grab the one at index 0 - (which will be the one with the lowest associated float)

I came across orderedDictionary's but I don't fully understand them and don't know how appropriate they are for my needs. I thought they were just a dictionary that allowed you to also index into them, but they aren't a template class?

Comment: Will you add new items to the list once it is filled once?

Comment: What don't you understand about `SortedList` and `OrderedDictionary`? You have not explained your use case completely.

Comment: So if you have a bunch of <int,float> pairs, you want to sort by the float but also have fast access by int, right?

Comment: Yes I will be adding new items, but I don't need to access by int - just grab the one with the lowest associated float value.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want a SortedSet:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx

If you are not using .net 4.0, its available in the PowerCollection project:
http://powercollections.codeplex.com/

Example with .Net4.0 SortedSet

```
SortedSet<float> set = new SortedSet<float>( );
set.Add(13.3f);
set.Add(0.5f);
set.Add(5.5f);

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Minimum Value: {0}", set.Min)); // prints 0.5
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Maximum Value: {0}", set.Max)); // prints 13.3

foreach (float f in set)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
// prints:
// 0.5
// 5.5
// 13.3

// using custom IComparer<float>, see implementation below
set = new SortedSet<float>(new FloatDescComparere());

set.Add(13.3f);
set.Add(0.5f);
set.Add(5.5f);

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Minimum Value: {0}", set.Min)); // prints 13.3
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Maximum Value: {0}", set.Max)); // prints 0.5

foreach (float f in set)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
// prints:
// 13.3
// 5.5
// 0.5
```

Desc IComparer:

```
private class FloatDescComparere : IComparer<float>
{
    public int Compare(float x, float y)
    {
        if (y > x)
            return 1;
        else if (x > y)
            return -1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what they are a little?

Comment: I Added a little example on how to use the SortedSet from .NET4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use a hash table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table, put the 'key' in the hash and search your element 'key' in the hash , if the hash has the key the you have that element . You must update each time you add a new element O(1) but you also have a find complexity of O(1).

Comment: I totally forgot about that he wanted to be sorted , i answered just for the finding part. Then just sort the elements and apply the hash.